# Is there a way to know if a post has been published through XML-RPC?

Tags: publish, xml-rpc, remote

It's all in the title, I'm looking for a way to know if a given post was published through XML-RPC, versus published by hand in the WP admin.

Pseudo code :

```
if( !wpse_from_xmlrpc( $post -> ID ) {
    // Doesn't come from XMLRPC
} else {
    // Comes from XMLRPC 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a custom field for a post which is saved via XMLRPC by using the action hook `xmlrpc_publish_post`. `wpse_from_xmlrpc()` could than check this custom field.

```
<?php
    add_action( 'xmlrpc_publish_post', 'add_xmlrpc_postmeta' );
    function add_xmlrpc_postmeta( $post_id ){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'send-by-xmlrpc', 1 );
    }

    function wpse_from_xmlrpc( $post_id ){
        $xmlrpc = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'send-by-xmlrpc', true );
        if( $xmlrpc == 1 )
            return true;
        return false;
    }
?>
```

More information on this hook can be found in *wp-includes/post.php*